# interrupting rsync created broken directory

Tags: filesystem, rsync

I was running `rsync -ar remote:folder local` and interrupted it with ctrl+c in the middle, but now I seem to have a broken subdirectory inside `local`.

If I try to `rm` or `ls` the subdirectory it just hangs forever without doing anything. Trying to `cd` into the subdirectory just freezes my entire terminal. `stat` works fine though.

How can I delete this subdirectory?

Comment: It sounds like the file system may be damaged and should be checked. On the other hand, `rsync` (or any other program not operating directly on the file system storage) shouldn't be able to damage the file system. The latter would either have to be buggy or have been inconsistent before running the program. What's the file system for `local` and what's the output of `stat local` (to maybe spot irregularities)?

Comment: Unfortunately, there was a power outage and the server was rebooted. After the reboot I was able to successfully delete the directory, so it's too late now to figure out what went wrong and why.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to unmount the filesystem and fsck it to fix this.

It looks like a you have a zombie process clinging on to that folder preventing it from being deleted.

rebooting should also clear this and allow a filesystem check if its needed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)